# UniStoredProc1:Field'_COLUMN1' not found (on android)

Tags: android, delphi, sql-server-2008-r2, unidac

I am able to get all the fields that my stored procedure (UniStoredProc1) is supposed to receive from the SQL Server.
This is the stored procedure :

```
declare @Navadna int
...
select @Navadna = COUNT(diet) from Mytable where diet ='1';
...
select @Navadna
```

The query produces _COLUMN1 as the result field.

Now in Delphi,with the fields editor of the UniStoredProc1 I can add all the fields in the component without a problem. In a classic window application everything works fine.

However, when I run it on Android I get :

UniStoredProc1:Field'_COLUMN1' not found.

Honestly,I do not know what am I doing wrong. As soon as UniConnection1 
connects it tells me the mentioned field is missing from the UniStoredProc1 thou the field is there. 
I tried (on button click :

```
procedure TTabbedForm.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
UniStoredProc1.Close;
UniStoredProc1.Prepare;
UniStoredProc1.ExecSQL;
UniStoredProc1.Open;
Label2.Text:=UniStoredProc1.FieldByName('__COLUMN1').AsString;
end;
```

But still the same result. The missing field.
What am I missing ? Any way to make this work ?
(Uni components are from Universal data Access components (devart)).
Delphi is Tokyo.

Comment: I added the UniDAC tag to your question. This behaviour is specific to the UniDAC data access components you are using... or at least, it would seem so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems all I had to do is alter my procedure on the server into :

```
select @Navadna as dieta
```

Then the field got reckognised. Alias seems to work.